# Find real height of any DOM element when browser zoomed

Tags: jquery, dom, height, zooming

Is there any way I can find the height of an element rendered on the DOM.

Even when I zoom-in/zoom-out, it should give me the actual height of the element. Currently I have used:

**HTML:**

```
<div >
    <span><img src="Desert.jpg" style="border:none;width:100px" id="imgdiv"/></span>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id="heightcalc" value="Find Height" />
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#heightcalc').click(function(){
    alert($('#imgdiv').height());
});
```

Now with 100% Zoom the height of the image 75. With 200%/300%/400% Zoom the height is same i.e. 75. My requirement is whenever I increase the Zoom the height should also change. Is there any way I can find the relative height of the image. I tried this in IE9, Chrome/Firefox - the result is the same.

Also, I did try with clientHeight, offsetHeight, outerHeight without no luck !

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Anirban

Comment: Why don't you find the zoom amount and multiply width and height with it?

Comment: [how to find zoom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)

Comment: @inhan  how do i find the zoom amount from the browser  ?

Comment: `.css('zoom'))` but some browsers have other css implementations such as **-moz-transform** which returns something like **scale(0.5)** You might actually write a conditional function to gather/change that.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to calculate the zooming effect for all browsers :

https://github.com/yonran/detect-zoom

through this could get the multiplication factor and then multiply this factor with the actual height of the element.

Here is the code : Please note I am using require js for our application.

```
require(["Widgets/detectzoom"], function (detectZoom) {
                zoom = detectZoom.ratios();
            });

            var heightofeachNode = ($("#dmcontent  ul li a span").eq(0).height()) * zoom.devicePxPerCssPx;
            self.pageSize = Math.round(($("#dmcontent").height()) / heightofeachNode) + 20 ;//20 - Its is the offset value
```

I have tested in all browser [IE9, Chrome18.0, FF 11.0]

Hope this helps.

Anirban

Comment: FYI: detect-zoom no longer works on FireFox or Chrome