# Changing css based on browser zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Upon a quick google search of **how to calculate the browser resolution with javascript** You get a fair amount of useful links on how to change the width (for example) of an element by calculating the screen width (with `screen.width`) then from there it is simple math to determine what you want the elements width to be. *COOL* However, that calculates the screen resolution, not the browsers current resolution if the browser is zoomed in, which is unfortunate. Sure you can set a constant width to a parent `div` and then the element wont be effected by a zoom at all. **BUT** is there a way to determine the total resolution of the view port left in a browser **AFTER** a zoom in or out has occured, rather than just the initial resolution? I cant seem to find anything...

Comment: You can use CSS media queries perhaps

Comment: I thought about media queries. but that leaves A LOT of css rules that could be simplified into one little js equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like what that user was looking for?

[Find real height of any DOM element when browser zoomed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022134/find-real-height-of-any-dom-element-when-browser-zoomed)

Try to follow it.